# Read text from command prompt that includes the character | (pipe)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When i run this snippet it blows up when i type the '|' character

```
SET /P _test=Enter your value: 
echo %_test%
```

```
Enter your value: Hello|World
'World' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I would like *%_test%* to contain the text **Hello|World** as supplied, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to safely echo an arbitrary string is to use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```cmd
set /P _test="Enter your value: "
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo(!_test!
endlocal
```

The odd-looking syntax `echo(` allows even empty strings, and also the strings `on`, `off` or `/?`, which would otherwise be interpreted as keywords or options by the `echo` command.

Regard that changes to the variable `_test` after `setlocal` are gong to be lost after `endlocal`.

Answer (score 0):

The following can be used to safely assign and input / output any string.

Note, Delayed expansion is Disabled at the time of string assignment in order to preserve `!` expansion symbols in strings.

```
@Echo off

    (Set LF=^


    %= Above Empty lines Required =%)

    Set ^"\n=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^"

::: - Macro to toggle delayed expansion and output / perform actions using var value
:::   %@Output% <VarName>
    Set @Output=For %%n in (1 2) Do if "%%n" == "2" (%\n%
        For /F "Tokens=1 Delims=, " %%G in ("!Param!") Do (%\n%
            Echo !%%~G! ^&^& Endlocal%\n%
        )%\n%
    ) Else Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion ^& Set Param=,

:Example
    CLS
    Call :input "Name" "Enter your Name:"
::: - To safely access any entered string Delayed Expansion should be enabled, especially with regards to redirection characters
::: - Conditional checks should be performed using doublequoting Ie: If "!VarName!" == "value" Command 
::: - Must be enabled AFTER variable is defined in order to correctly set expansion characters
    %@Output% Name
    Pause
Goto :Example

:input <VarName> <Prompt>
::: - preserve input of expansion characters
    Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    Set /P "Var=%~2"
::: - Ensure a value is assigned
    If "%Var%" == "" Goto :input
Endlocal & Set "%~1=%Var%"
Exit /b
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply enclose the string with quotes (") when you enter it

Comment: Besides the fact that quotes are also echoed then, this won't help when the string contains quotes on its own, particularly unbalanced ones...

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like  this:

```
echo "Put in your name"
read -a words
var="${words[@]}"
echo $var
```